# livewire modals mix --production deploy style error

Tags: laravel-livewire

I'm using [this](https://github.com/wire-elements/modal) livewire modal component. All works pretty well when I'm on local (`./vendor/bin/sail npm run watch`). When I run the command `./vendor/bin/sail npm run prod` to publish my app.js and app.css the modal doesn't respect the configured size on my livewire modal:

```
public static function modalMaxWidth(): string
{
   return '7xl';
}
```

This is my tailwind.config.js

```
const defaultTheme = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");

module.exports = {
    purge: {
        content: [
            "./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php",
            "./vendor/laravel/jetstream/**/*.blade.php",
            './vendor/wire-elements/modal/resources/views/*.blade.php',
            "./storage/framework/views/*.php",
            "./resources/views/**/*.blade.php",
        ],
        options: {
            safelist: [
                'sm:max-w-2xl'
            ]
        }
    },

    theme: {
        extend: {
            height: {
                '500': '500px',
            },
            width: {
                '110': '110px',
            },
            minHeight: {
                '450': '450px',
            },
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ["Nunito", ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
            borderWidth: {
                DEFAULT: "1px",
                0: "0",
                2: "2px",
                3: "3px",
                4: "4px",
                5: "5px",
                6: "6px",
                7: "7px",
                8: "8px",
                9: "9px",
                10: "10px",
            },
            padding: {
                am: "17px",
                bm: "18px",
                cm: "19px",
            },
            screens: {
                iphone4: "400px",
                // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... }
            },
            margin: {}
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        require("@tailwindcss/forms"),
        require("@tailwindcss/typography")
    ],
};
```

This is my package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.1",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.4.0",
        "alpinejs": "^3.5.2",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "postcss-import": "^14.0.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.2.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@alpinejs/focus": "^3.12.0"
    }
}
```

This is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte": "^3.7",
        "laravel/cashier": "^13.8",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.54",
        "laravel/jetstream": "^2.4",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.2",
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.5",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.4",
        "wire-elements/modal": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.19",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.8"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "admin-lte--install": [
            "@php artisan adminlte:install"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

is it something that I'm missing?
Thanks for your time.